# Moving the player like in the famous Snake Game

Tags: swift

I'm making a game where the player i suppose to avoid balls coming in on the screen. The balls will be coming in from any angle, and it's game over when the player makes contact with another ball. My only problem is the movement of the player. I want it to move sort of like the famous Snake Game without the player leaving a trace like the snake does. So, I want the player to move with a constant speed at a certain direction, and when the player touches on the left side of the screen, the player goes left, and when the player touches on the right side, the player goes right. But when the player touches on either side, the player shouldn't move like 90 degrees or something, it should move softly to either side. So if the player wants to move like 90 degrees, he/she would have to hold their finger on the screen longer.

In this video you can see exactly how I want the player to move. Although you can ignore the trace the player leaves behind.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhwaZvsNAA0

Here you have my code:

The random class the randomized the balls spawning:

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

public extension CGFloat {

public static func randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: CGFloat, secondNum: 
CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(firstNum - 
secondNum) + firstNum

}

}
```

The player class:

```
import SpriteKit

struct ColliderType {

static let Player: UInt32 = 1
static let Score: UInt32 = 2
static let Enemy: UInt32 = 3

}

class Player: SKSpriteNode {

func initialize() {
    self.name = "Player"
    self.zPosition = 1
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.height / 
2)
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Player
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Score | 
ColliderType.Enemy
}

}
```

This is the gameplayscene class:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameplayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var player = Player()

var ball = SKSpriteNode()

var ballIsTouched = false

var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
var score = 0

var counter = Timer()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    initialize()
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: 
UIEvent?) {


    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if atPoint(location).name == "Retry" {
            self.removeAllActions()
            self.removeAllChildren()
            initialize()
        }

        if atPoint(location).name == "Quit" {
            let mainmenu = MainMenuScene(fileNamed: "MainMenuScene")
            mainmenu!.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            self.view?.presentScene(mainmenu!, transition: 
SKTransition.fade(withDuration: TimeInterval(1)))
        }

    }

}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "Player" {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if firstBody.node?.name == "Player" && secondBody.node?.name == 
"Score" {
        incrementCoinScore()
        secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()
    }

    if firstBody.node?.name == "Player" && secondBody.node?.name == 
"Enemy" {
        playerDied()
        firstBody.node?.removeFromParent()
    }

}

func initialize() {

    score = 0

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    createPlayer()
    createBackground()
    spawnEnemy1()
    spawnEnemy2()
    spawnEnemy3()
    spawnEnemy4()
    createLabel()

    counter = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(1), 
target: self, selector: "incrementScore", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func createPlayer() {
    player = Player(imageNamed: "Player")
    player.initialize()
    player.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.addChild(player)
}

func createBackground() {
    let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BG")
    bg.name = "BG"
    bg.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    bg.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.addChild(bg)
}

func createEnemy1() {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Orange")
    ball.name = "Enemy"
    ball.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    ball.zPosition = 1
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 
2)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    ball.position.y = self.size.height + 100
    ball.position.x = CGFloat.randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: -345, 
secondNum: 345)

    self.addChild(ball)

    let destination = self.frame.height * 2
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: -destination, duration: 
TimeInterval(10))
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    ball.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]), withKey: "MoveEnemy1")
}

func spawnEnemy1() {

    let spawn = SKAction.run({ () -> Void in
        self.createEnemy1()
    })

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(1))
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])

    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence), withKey: "SpawnEnemy1")
}

func createEnemy2() {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Green")
    ball.name = "Enemy"
    ball.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    ball.zPosition = 1
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 
 2)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    ball.position.y = -self.size.height + 100
    ball.position.x = CGFloat.randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: -345, 
secondNum: 345)

    self.addChild(ball)

    let destination = self.frame.height * 2
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: destination, duration: 
TimeInterval(10))
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    ball.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]), withKey: "MoveEnemy2")
}

func spawnEnemy2() {

    let spawn = SKAction.run({ () -> Void in
        self.createEnemy2()
    })

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(1))
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])

    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence), withKey: "SpawnEnemy2")
}

func createEnemy3() {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Blue")
    ball.name = "Enemy"
    ball.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    ball.zPosition = 1
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 
2)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    ball.position.x = -self.size.width + 200
    ball.position.y = CGFloat.randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: -637, 
secondNum: 637)

    self.addChild(ball)

    let destination = self.frame.height * 2
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(x: destination, duration: 
TimeInterval(10))
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    ball.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]), withKey: "MoveEnemy3")
}

func spawnEnemy3() {

    let spawn = SKAction.run({ () -> Void in
        self.createEnemy3()
    })

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(1))
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])

    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence), withKey: "SpawnEnemy3")
}

func createEnemy4() {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Yellow")
    ball.name = "Enemy"
    ball.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    ball.zPosition = 1
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 
2)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    ball.position.x = self.size.width + 200
    ball.position.y = CGFloat.randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: -637, 
secondNum: 637)

    self.addChild(ball)

    let destination = self.frame.height * 2
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(x: -destination, duration: 
TimeInterval(10))
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    ball.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]), withKey: "MoveEnemy4")
}

func spawnEnemy4() {

    let spawn = SKAction.run({ () -> Void in
        self.createEnemy4()
    })

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(1))
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])

    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence), withKey: "SpawnEnemy4")
}


func createLabel() {
    scoreLabel.zPosition = 3
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: -320, y: 600)
    scoreLabel.fontName = "Verdana"
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 70
    scoreLabel.text = "0"
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)
}

func incrementScore() {
    score += 1
    scoreLabel.text = String(score)
}

func incrementCoinScore() {
    score += 5
}

func playerDied() {

    counter.invalidate()

    let highscore = GameManager.instance.getHighscore()

    if highscore < score {
        GameManager.instance.setHighscore(highscore: score)
    }

    let retry = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Retry")
    let quit = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Quit")

    retry.name = "Retry"
    retry.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    retry.position = CGPoint(x: -150, y: -50)
    retry.zPosition = 2
    retry.setScale(0)

    quit.name = "Quit"
    quit.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    quit.position = CGPoint(x: 150, y: -50)
    quit.zPosition = 2
    quit.setScale(0)

    let scaleUp = SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: TimeInterval(0.5))

    retry.run(scaleUp)
    quit.run(scaleUp)

    self.addChild(retry)
    self.addChild(quit)

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to read your question a couple of times to understand what you ment. but since I played "achtung die curve" back in the days It finally made sens. here is a working example of what you want. Copy - Paste - Examine

Feel free to ask if theres anything you don't fully understand

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {

    let playerSpeed = 3
    let turnRate:CGFloat = 0.03
    var isAlive = true

    // this is the initializer for the class. when you make an instance
    // of your class, this function will be called. and this is were you setup your player.
    init() {

    //create a texture for your player
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
    //setup other stuff you already have in your own code.
    // when you create an instance in your createPlayer function do like this
   // let player = Player()
   // player.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
   //self.addChild(player)

  // note that you do not need to call the init manually.

    // since your player class is an subclass of SKSpriteNode you have to call super.init().
    // This is the initializer of your superclass (SKSpriteNode), 
    // I would suggest you read more about subclassing and this will make sens. 
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size:texture.size())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func turnLeft(){

        // add to the current rotation by a factor of turnRate
        self.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: turnRate, duration: 0))

    }

    func turnRight(){

        // subtract from the current rotation by a factor of turnRate
        self.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -turnRate, duration: 0))

    }

    func move(){

        // this gives us a position in the scene space that is 3 points(or what ever value playerSpeed is) 
        // infront of the player. basicly we convert (x:0, y:3) from the player coordinates. to the scene coordinate.
        // Even when the player rotates in the scene. the (x:0, y:3) is allways the same in the player coordinate.
        let newPosition = convert(CGPoint(x:0, y:playerSpeed), to: scene!)
        self.position = newPosition

    }


}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let player = Player()

    var shouldTurnLeft = false
    var shouldTurnRight = false

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


        addChild(player)


    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self)

        if (touchLocation?.x)! > 0{

            shouldTurnRight = true
        }
        else if (touchLocation?.x)! < 0{

            shouldTurnLeft = true

        }

    }


    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        shouldTurnLeft = false
        shouldTurnRight = false
    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

        // if the player is alive. move the player every frame
   if player.isAlive{
        player.move()

        if shouldTurnLeft {
            player.turnLeft()
        }
        if shouldTurnRight{
            player.turnRight()
        }
   }




        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one problem though. When I added the code, I got an error from my createPlayer function. More precisely in the line "player = Player(imageNamed: "Player")". Swift wants me to change "imageNamed" to "coder" and when I do that I get another issue in the same line saying "cannot convert value of type "string" to expected argument type "NSCoder"". Do you have any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Yeah, well your code its not really compatible with the code In my answer. what I meant was that if you copy my code into a new empty project it does work the way you described you wanted it to work. then evaluate HOW it works and then customise the concept to fit your code.

Comment: But this is the problem you are having with your current code: when you create an instance of your player class in your createPlayer function. you try to provide an image as a parameter. player = Player(imageNamed: "Player"). in your player class you don't accept any parameter in the init function. to be honest I never even seen initialize() before. just the standard init. I will update my answer to give you some more insight of how it should look :)

Comment: if you still have trouble. post your code here and il show/ explain in real time: https://codeshare.io/5w4qP7

Comment: Thanks, that totally did it!! :)

Comment: I have one issue left. I've added the code and added my previous code as well. It works until the player dies, then I get an error in the line "let newPosition = convert(CGPoint(x:0, y:playerSpeed), to: scene!)". The error says EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONS and in the output it says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Do you know how to solve the issue? I tried invalidating the player.move() in some ways but couldn't solve it. If you need the code I can email it to you. I'm also from Stockholm so you could answer in swedish if so. :)

Comment: Tjenare, kul att fler svenskar håller på med SpriteKit. Jag uppdaterade mitt svar och la till en variable i player classen: isAlive = true

sedan I update funktionen:
if player.isAlive{
   player.move
}

sedan behöver du bara sätta player.isAlive = false när spelaren dör.

Comment: om du tar bort hela player instansen när spelaren dör får du flytta isAlive till gameScene istället för player classen

Comment: Grymt, tack! Nu har jag bara ett litet problem kvar. Det är när spelaren dött och jag trycker på "Retry" så börjar spelet om som det bör, förutom att bollen inte längre syns. Jag lade till self.removeAllActions, self.removeAllChildren och Initialize() inom retry-knappen som jag alltid gjort och det har alltid funkat, men bollen syns inte längre. Ska sägas att jag tog bort createPlayer() funktionen helt.

Comment: ja nu vet jag inte exakt hur din nya kod ser ut. Men om du kör removeAllChildren så tar du ju bort alla nodes i scene. så då behöver du ju lägga till spelaren igen när spelet startar om. Och eftersom du kör initialize()  på retry knappen så bör du rimligen lägga till addChild(player) där också :)

Comment: Jo, precis. Jag har testat att lägga till addchild(player) i initialize() men när jag trycker på retry så spawnar bollen men utan rörelse. :(

Comment: har du ändrat isAlive till true? efter du lägger till bollen